# How can I update a row on database by iterating through a stringbuilder?

Tags: java, iteration, stringbuilder

I am trying to update my database according to the data of `"replace"`. `replace` have few columns of data and I want to update those columns in my database `abcd` accordingly.

But when I run this code only the last column that means the last data gets updated in DB and I guess the iteration is not right in this case.

So please help me. I appreciate your suggestions.

```
private static void updateDB(HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> map) throws ConfigException, SQLException {
        MConfig config = ScriptsTools.init();
        ConnPool select = ScriptsTools.openPool("database", config);
        Connection write = select.getWrite();
         StringBuilder replace = new StringBuilder();

         replace.append("REPLACE INTO abcd (a,b,c,d,e) values ");

         Iterator<Entry<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> pair = it.next();

                replace.append("('");
                replace.append(pair.getKey());
                replace.append("','");
                replace.append(pair.getValue().get(2));
                replace.append("','");
                replace.append(pair.getValue().get(11));
                replace.append("',");
                replace.append("now()");
                replace.append(",");
                replace.append("now()");
                replace.append("), ");


            }

            replace.delete(replace.length()-2, replace.length());
            //System.out.println("Query : "+replace.toString());
            String words = replace.toString();
            System.out.println(words);

            Statement st = write.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(replace.toString());
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you use a `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement` is easy to print the query to be executed on the database using the following command

```
System.out.println(replace.toString());
```

Take it and execute it in your preferred database client and check if it works as expected.

Comment: No actually thats not a big problem. I am able to see my query properly and it is working fine but when I try to update the data in database only the last row of the query gets updated like if my query shows the result as this ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)) then only (g,h,i)  get updated in one column. Please suggest how can I update other data of my query also. Thanks for your help.